Do I understand the differences between cross-reference and cross-check in American English correctly?
I know there is a similar question on here but I am really not sure whether I finally managed to grasp the difference between cross reference and cross check when cross-check means "comparing two or more things". I know that cross-reference can also mean that a book references, let's say, another book whose subject matter is similar.
I have done some research, however it wasn't fruitful because there is no website that covers the difference between these two verbs. So please, help me understand the difference between them because I'd like to use them naturally.
Can native speakers just tell me whether I understood the difference between cross-check and cross reference correctly?
I have consulted many dictionaries and that didn't work. I really want to know how to use these words correctly.
Here is my understanding of the way they differ:
Cross-reference means that someone takes two or more different sources and compares them to find the similarities between them.
Cross-checking is establishing whether there's consistency between two or more related sources or simply put, things.
If my understanding is correct then the way I have used these words in the following sentences is correct, isn't it?:
"When cooking, I always make sure to cross-check the steps I take against the instructions in the cookbook." (Here it's about related things, namely the steps one needs to take to cook a dish. The person cooking takes the necessary steps to prepare the dish well and they compare their steps to the instructions in the cookbook to make sure there is consistency between how they execute each step and how the cookbook describes the steps should be taken.
"The policeman cross-checked what the boys said against the CCTV footage." (Same here. Basically two related sources. The boy says the guy in the blue jacket started the fight, so the policeman looks at the footage to determine to what extent what the boy said matches what the CCTV footage shows.)
"When learning a language, people tend to cross-reference the definition of one word in a dictionary with other definitions from other dictionaries." (Here, we're dealing with several unrelated sources as the dictionaries have no connection to one another and they might define words slightly differently. The learners compare the definitions to find similarities between the definitions.)
"A detective cross-references three witness statements with one another."
Again, three unrelated sources and the detective is looking for pieces of information in the witness statements that agree.
For example:
Witness A says: The suspect was 6 feet tall, had a tattoo on his face, was Caucasian, and had blond hair.
Witness B says the same but they assert the hair was platinum blond.
Witness C says describes the suspect the exact same way but they say the hair color was a mix of brunet and blond.
Is my understanding of the difference between cross-check and cross-reference correct? Habe I used the words correctly? Please correct me if I am wrong. I'd really like to understand the difference and use these terms correctly.
Thank you in advance!

Well, cross-check doesn't come up as often as one might expect. Check the proceeds against the actual deposits. And I cross-checked all the data, Commander is probably Star Trek or something like that.

Yeah, "A detective checks three witness statements against one another" would probably be more common, and same for many other examples. You could also use "reference" to mean "check (against other information)", but it has more of a context of consulting a reference book or other gold standard, and is quite formal. As I've said before, there's no hard and fast difference of meaning, and opinions will differ.

But is my general understanding of how to use these verbs correct?

You've already posted near-identical questions twice. Unfortunately, if people on this site aren't interested in answering a question, you just won't get an answer; it isn't appropriate to keep reposting things.

You have enough reputation to "start a bounty" on your first question to attract new answers; that's the right way to deal with not yet having one that satisfies you. Though I haven't contributed because I don't know how best to explain that both these are pretty darn rare and specialized, and not worth the importance they seem to hold to you.

This is just English.
Cross-referencing versus cross-checking
cross-reference involves taking an item of knowledge or fact and seeing if it exists in two different reliable sources. For example, you take some fact or piece of knowledge such as "The Earth revolves around the sun" and then you find out if it occurs in at least two trustworthy sources (not in The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy!) such as encyclopedias or scientific texts. One fact or item and two or more reliable sources of fact about it. At the least, it always involves three things: the fact to be checked and the two places where its presence is given as a reference.
Summary: the original location of the fact (such as in an academic paper) and two reliable references for it.
cross-checking involves only two things. One item or fact is found to exist in another than the place you have at hand or at first.
For example, you, as an association, have a list of participants you wish to invite to an event. Another association also has a list. You are cooperating in organizing the event. If you compare one list to the other, you are cross-checking it. Cross-checking involves two  things, not three.
If two members of a family make shopping lists, the lists can be cross-checked. One list is compared to the other to make sure they are the same.
Summary: one thing compared to another such as a list or recipe or piece of computer code.

Thank you but what about cross-reference?

@Idk29 It's there.

If the Earth actually revolving around the Sun counts as the third thing, then so do the actual participants and the items to be bought. There are thus three things in each of the examples: two sources and whatever they are about. All the examples in this answer seem to be cases of cross-checking. I would reserve cross-referencing only for the cases in which there is actual referencing. As Greybeard pointed out in a comment on another incarnation of this question, cross- is of limited relevance to answering this question; what is crucial is the difference between check and reference.

@jsw29 If you write a thesis, and put in "x is y" (the item or point), you then go to two outside sources for references: two reliable books, authors, scientific texts to make sure you've got it right and which you may or may not use.
